# Launching jupyter notebook not from anaconda navigator

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm not expert. I have installed Anaconda Navigator and nothing more. Now for opening Jupyter Notebook, I simply open Anaconda Navigator and then open it.

But it takes a while.

Could I simply open Jupyter in a more faster way?

If not, then could it be possible, if I install something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply go to command prompt / anaconda prompt and type jupyter notebook